# .Net application on IBM Websphere Portal

Tags: .net, websphere, portal

How can a .Net web application be deployed on IBM Websphere Portal? I googled on this but the close I could get was the MainSoft product which converts MSIL to Java byte code.We have IBM Websphere Portal licenses but now the as per the new organisation guildelines(due to a takeover) we are supposed to move to .Net.Can we make use of our existing IBM Websphere Portal Server?

Answer (score 0):

Read following. It will be helpful

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/net-development-the-ibm-websphere-porta/210500054?pgno=1